# Introduce fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android and I have developed an app with only activities, now I want to change this and have created a navigation drawer with fragments.

The problem is that I don't know how to change the activities to fragments.

**What I Have Tried:**

First of all, I create a `BlankFragment` and I adapted it to my activity, the fragment is called BlankFragment at the moment, this is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="games.asee.videogames_asee_project.BlankFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listTOP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the class of the fragment (I have only modified the code in onCreateView) :

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            JuegosOperaciones crud = JuegosOperaciones.getInstance(getContext());
            items = crud.getTOP();
            adapter = new JuegoAdapter(getContext(), items);
            ListView itemsListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listTOP);
            itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        }
```

But I don't know how to call the fragment in the navigationDrawer, I tried calling `getFragmentManager` but the app doesn't do anything!

```
} else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
           // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.listTOP,new BlankFragment()).commit();
        }
```

If you need to see more code just tell me.

Thank you guys again!

Comment: As a starter try out this example: https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in your main activity initialize the navigation drawer items and set up it. after when click on navigation items replace the fragments on frame layout
using this code

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.frameForPane, my_fragment);
        fTransaction.commit();
        mainDrawer.closeDrawers();
```

and set the MainActivity.class using this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    // ...



    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ...From section above...

        // Find our drawer view

        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

        // Setup drawer view

        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    }



    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(

                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override

                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);

                        return true;

                    }

                });

    }



    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked

        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;

        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:

                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

                break;

            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:

                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;

                break;

            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:

                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;

                break;

            default:

                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

        }



        try {

            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();



        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView

        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        // Set action bar title

        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

        // Close the navigation drawer

        mDrawer.closeDrawers();

    }



    // ...

}
```

this would help you to integrate the open the next fragments clicking on navigation item.